# Stanford NER tagger

Tags: computational-linguistics, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to use Stanford NER tagger from the following link:[NER tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process)
I output format I have chosen 'slashTags' and entered the following sentence:

```
 While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus
 efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.
```

Here is what I got back:

```
    While/O in/O France/LOCATION,/O Christine/PERSON Lagarde/PERSON
 discussed/O short-term/O stimulus/O
    efforts/O in/O a/O recent/O interview/O with/O the/O Wall/O Street/O Journal/O./O
```

Location, person and organization tags make sense, but what does `O` tag mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an inline (choosen with slashTags) format, the `/0` tag is necessary to denote everything that is not a named entity. You may find this superfluous on first sight, but when there are more layers of tagging, zero tags become essential for the interpretation of the corpus.

P.S. Here is a link to a [Stanford NER tutorial](https://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/resource/227/).